# Network Manager "forgets" my network

Tags: networking, network-manager, kde

It's been a long time since I last tampered with Linux desktop, and I wanted to see how it's doing, so I put KDE Neon on an old laptop. It works very well and I find it amazing, however I bumped into a weird annoyance concerning wifi.
When I boot the machine it correctly connects to my wifi network (ordinary router, default settings, always worked with every device). After a while it shows a notification saying "Connection {{my_network}} deactivated". When I click on system tray wifi icon it shows all available networks except mine.
I tried scanning network from command line with `nmcli dev wifi` but it yields the same result: all networks are listed except mine. I also tried restarting Network Manager with `sudo service network-manager restart`, to no avail. The connection is restored upon reboot.
What's happening here? Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: KDE Neon isn't supported [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Try asking at https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DKBose: sorry, I thought it was an ubuntu flavor. Migrating.